In a formula, can I set a cell that changes in relation to time?
I have a record of dates and values.
Column A holds dates,  column B holds values.
In my formula I am calculating the difference between a cell in the past and the latest cell:
=B25-LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),B:B)

where the B column contains the values.
B25 is for a date 10 weeks ago.
I increment B25 each week.  So next week it will be B26.
In this way my difference calculation is for the previous 10 weeks.
Is there a formula that will allow me to select the B cell based on the date in the A column being 10 weeks earlier than today?

now()-70 with index() & match() as a first thought

@Solar Mike.  I've looked into that and I can't see how it could help.  Can you enlarge on your answer?

Well, here is an example based on what I said with the suggestion of today():

You can change 150 to 70 etc
You should check out the behaviour of match() with the matching parameters of -1,0 or 1.
To save typing:
TODAY()-E4

INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E6,A:A,1))


Pardon me if I've misunderstood the question.
If you have Microsoft 365, could you try this (for simplicity I have entered dates varying by week) (formula entered in C1 in the example):
=LAMBDA(dates_col, values_col,
    LET(
        dates_col, FILTER(
            dates_col,
            LEN(TRIM(dates_col)) > 0
        ),
        value_10_weeks_ago, LAMBDA(date_,
            LOOKUP(
                WEEKNUM(date_) - 10,
                MAP(dates_col, LAMBDA(d, WEEKNUM(d))),
                values_col
            )
        ),
        BYROW(dates_col, value_10_weeks_ago)
    )
)(A1:A100, B1:B100)


